# Set inside and outside borders on one line

Tags: vb.net, closedxml

Is it possible to do this on one line?
dataRange.Style.Border.SetInsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin).SetOutsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin) isn't correct syntax

```
        dataRange.Style.Border.SetInsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin)
        dataRange.Style.Border.SetOutsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin)
```

Comment: This would probably be well asked on codegolf.se; masters of code brevity :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dataRange.Style.Border.SetInsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin) : dataRange.Style.Border.SetOutsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin)
```

Comment: yes thank you, that works, it never occurred to me to do it like that. ClosedXML code can become a bit long winded so I'm trying to rationalise it while still retaining its readability

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it seems to have some sort of fluent syntax in that SetXxxBorder returns a Style. I'd hence be interested to know if this works:

```
dataRange.Style.Border.SetOutsideBorder(...).Border.SetInsideBorder(...);
```

You also have vb.net's statement separator:

```
    Dim t = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin : Dim b = dataRange.Style.Border : b.InsideBorder = t : b.OutsideBorder = t
```

If you're using eg Thin border a lot it would reduce wordiness to declare it elsewhere (like I did with `t`) using a reasonably descriptive but shorter name